# Docfx Russian language search

Tags: docfx, lunrjs

How to make docfx to search in Russian language?
It searches English words just fine, but not Russian words. I tried to debug it and can see that it uses **lunr** library for search. How can I replace standard lunr library with Russian lunr in docfx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be quite easy:
In order to support other languages apart from those which supports lunr use this repo:
https://github.com/MihaiValentin/lunr-languages

Open `search-worker.js` file from docfx and modify it a bit as readme at github suggest:

Add imports

```
importScripts('lunr.stemmer.support.js');
importScripts('lunr.ru.js');
```

Copy these files from github to the folder with lunr.js

Modify the following method:

```
var lunrIndex = lunr(function() {
      this.pipeline.remove(lunr.stopWordFilter);
Add this line...>this.use(lunr.ru);
      this.ref('href');
```

Enjoy.